# Preventing someone from trying to steal my Gmail account using account recovery

Tags: gmail, account-recovery

Gmail is asking me if it's me that's trying to recover my account (from another continent!) and I of course say no every time (happens every few days, always from the same place).

Am I at the mercy of this person doing this every few days, hoping that I'll accidentally click yes? Is there a way to prevent certain regions/continents from attempting to recover accounts so I can be done with this?

I've looked through Google's "help" section but it doesn't help one bit regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exactly prevent them from trying to enter your email and clicking "forgot password", but there are a few things you can do to make sure you're still secure.

1. Use two factor authentication on your Google account. Google has an authenticator app that is used to link to your Gmail. This is more secure than using your phone number as a two factor authentication method because someone can spoof your phone number (if they really want to get access to your account). If you're very concerned you can get a physical hardware token that has to be plugged into your computer before you can sign in. This means that even if they have your password, it won't matter because they have to physically have the USB key to sign in to your account.
2. You could review other security settings/change your password to make sure you're still secure.

I recommend #1 to everyone. Two factor is a must.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to block certain locations (countries, regions, continents) to be used to recover a Google Account password.

Please send your feedback to Google by using [Google Feedback](https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/)

**Reference**

- [Avoid getting locked out of your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7684753?hl=en)